# How to get a Vector3 rotation between two Quaternions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I'm writing a script which rotates a `Rigidbody` using a `Configurable Joint`. I've got the `targetRotation` figured out, but now I'm struggling with `targetAngularVelocity`, which should help me avoid wobbliness if set correctly.

`targetAngularVelocity` is defined like this in the [documantation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ConfigurableJoint.html): "This is a `Vector3`. It defines the desired angular velocity that the joint should rotate into". The problem is that I don't know how to get this `Vector3` based on two `Quaternions` - current rotation of the object and the target rotation.

Am I not understanding it correctly? Is there a function that returns a rotation vector based on two `Quaternions`?

Comment: Velocity is just the speed at which you want it to move... It's like asking "I have point A and point B, how do I combine them to get the speed between the two"...

Comment: @RonBeyer Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I'm using this `Configurable Joint` to rotate between points A and B. Now I want to set the `targetAngularVelocity` to match that rotation - so I need to get a rotation vector based on two `Quaternions`.

Comment: You could try to use the euler space representions `quaternionB.eulerAngles - quaternionA.eulerAngles` if you mean that. A bit hard to tell though without your code

Comment: @derHugo Already tried that, doesn't seem to be working. The values this returns are completely diferent from the actual `angularVelocity` of the object (which is rotated to the `targetRotation` by the Spring drive - so they should match, or at least be similar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So mathematically a Quaternion represents the orientation of a rigid body. Consider the forward problem first, and see how the orientation **q_1** transforms to another orientation **q_2** after a rotational velocity **ω** is applied for *t* time.

Mathematically the rotation vector has a magnitude *ω* and a direction **k** such that **ω** = ω* **k**

This is done with quaternion multiplication as

**q_2** = **q_ω** * **q_1**

Where **q_ω** represents a rotation about the axis of **k** of an angle θ=ω*t.

In reverse, you need to find **q_ω** with

```
var q_ω = q_2 * Quaternion.Inverse(q_1);
```

and extract the rotation axis and angle

```
q_ω.ToAngleAxis(out float angle, out Vector3 axis);
```

and compose the rotational velocity vector, that corresponds to this transformation in `time` seconds.

```
var ω = (angle/time)*axis;
```

Comment: Wow good that there is always that one guy knowing the stuff about Quaternions ^^

Comment: Although I know a lot of 3D physics and rigid body mechanics and I am a C# programmer, I haven't actually ever played around with Unity. The answer to your question seems that it needs knowledge of the simulation engine in Unity which I don't have.

Comment: @derHugo indeed I know a lot of quaternions. Thanks for the comment.